¿PRESTASHOP 8.1.5 Multitenda?
He instalado un PS 8.1.5 multitienda compartiendo productos, he migrado con el modulo PS Migrate y me ha migrado los productos correctamente a las dos tiendas.
Cuando doy de alta en el panel un producto, aun marcando aplicar cambios para todas las tiendas, crea el producto en una sola tienda.
He revisado la bbdd y efectivamente solo crea un registro asociado a la tienda donde se ha creado el producto.
¿Alguien ha tenido este problema?
Un saludo.

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

respuesta, usando el buscador te podras percatar que tu post es el unico relacionado a ese problema, por ente la respuesta es no nadie mas a tenido es e problema.

ha te recomiendo hacer el [tour] en el cual podras encontrar algunos datos de como funciona el sitio ...

Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque no es una pregunta sobre programación y está fuera de tópico en SO.

si alguna de las respuesta te ha servido podes marcarla como resuelta, eso te dara al menos 2 puntos de reputacion que te seran utiles en un futuro. saludos.

En este hilo culpan a la versión de PHP:
https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/1077986-los-productos-nuevos-no-se-muestran-en-todas-las-tiendas/

Respuesta: usando el buscador del sitio te podras percatar que tu post es el unico relacionado a ese problema:

Por ente la respuesta es NO, nadie más a tenido ese problema aqui.
